# How to stop task notification mail,whenever the task has been created/assigned?

Tags: email, tasks, task-notifications

How to stop task notification mail, whenever the task has been created/assigned?

Where to remove setting, I tried settings->calendar&remainder->unchecked task notification mail, but it is still firing. Can we write any trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to disable the email notification on Task creation/assignment, we need to do:

1. From your personal settings, enter Activity Reminders in the Quick
   Find box, then select Activity Reminders.
2. Deselect Email me when someone assigns me a task.

As you mentioned that you have already done the same, but still getting the mails, I would suggest you check there isn't any workflow written that fires the email alert.

Let me know the findings!